# How to set up table loop for Microchip assembly language

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip

I am learning assembly language to display seven segment on the picboard.
I need let seven segment display 00 to FF, and 00-99(decimal)
I am stuck on the table read.
How to let the table automatic read again when it hits F or 9.
Here is my code:

```
Loop
    TBLRD*+     ; Read byte from table, increment pointer
    MOVF    TABLAT, w
    movwf   PORTE       ; Move W to PORTE
    call    Delay_333ms ; Call delay subroutine
    goto    Loop        ; Repeat loop

PatTbl
    dw   h'6'       
    dw   h'5b'      
    dw   h'159'     
    dw   h'66'      
    dw   h'6d'  
    dw   h'7d'
    dw   h'7'
    dw   h'7f'
    dw   h'6f'     
    dw   h'77'
    dw   h'7c'
    dw   h'39'
    dw   h'3f'
    dw   h'79'
    dw   h'71'  
    dw   h'3f'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest technique is masking, it works like that: If your max.value is 0x0f and it is stored in a variable of byte size, say ( max is 0x0ff ) you create a mask equal to max.value and AND with this mask after each increment.

```
#define MASK 0b00001111

uint8_t value = 0;


while(1) {    
    value = (value++) & MASK;
}
```

'Value' will be cycling from 0 to 0x0f.

In your assembly example you'll need to have separate storage for the pointer to a table and the value you're changing. Then you will be incrementing the value, masking it, and then adding it to the table pointer.